# How does "object" work in the collections.defaultdict example "%(object)s"?

Tags: python-3.x

In the Python3 documentation for collections.defaultdict(), the Examples sections gives an unusual use of "%()s" formatting:

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda: value

d = defaultdict(constant_factory('<missing>'))

d.update(name='John', action='ran')

'%(name)s %(action)s to %(object)s' % d

>>> 'John ran to <missing>'
```

I'm familiar with the "%()s" notation (though bonus points if someone can point me to the documentation for this usage) but my question is, where does "object" come from?  I can't figure out how this works because there is no "object" key in the dict:

```
print(f"{d=}")

>>> d=defaultdict(<function constant_factory.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fa088a5ab80>, {'name': 'John', 'action': 'ran'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string formatting line told Python to plug the value of `d['object']` into the string.  The way a defaultdict works is that if you refer to a key that is not there, it will create an entry with that key and the default value from the factory you gave it.  So in this case, when the format string referred to `d['object']`, the defaultdict created an entry with a key of `'object'` and a value of `'<missing>'` and duly plugged the value into the string.

I would guess that the output of the contents of d you showed was run before the format string reference created the `'object':'<missing>'` entry.

For bonus points, so-called "Old Style" string formatting operations with `%` are documented at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting.  Different string formatting facilities were introduced in Python 3.

Comment: Makes sense.  Excellent explanation.  Bonus Points!